# "make: *** [all] Error 1" for compiling tex files

Tags: makefile, latex

I tried to write a makefile to compile the tex file, but an error made me crazy. I have simplified my makefile like below

```
all: main.tex
    xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode  ./main.tex
```

but the error still exists as follows.

```
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I also tried to directly run the command in terminal:

```
xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode  ./main.tex
```

I have a successful compilation. Similar errors have been found in [make: *** [ ] Error 1 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535548/make-error-1-error) and [make: *** [ ] Error 1 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535548/make-error-1-error), but the solution does not work for me. Is there anyone could help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a simpler `xelatex` command you can test? Does the Make command compile the tex file? Do you know the return value of the `xelatex` command?

Comment: I cannot use a simple xelatex for the latex file (because it would give me error). If add the nonstop mode, anyway, the pdf would successfully generate and no error appears. I have run the command "xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode ./main.tex" in terminal (not in the makefile), it works. I have also tried to use this makefile for other tex files, it also works. But this makefile does not work for the special tex files.

Answer (score 0):

A very dirty and useful trick is to force true in order to avoid the error and to let make continue:

```
$(FICTEX).pdf: $(FICTEX).aux $(BBL)
    $(PDFLATEX) $(FICTEX)||true
    $(PDFLATEX) $(FICTEX)||true
```

Comment: This can also be achieved by putting a minus sign before each row in which errors should be ignored, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2670143/2207840). Alternatively, one can also pass the `-i` flag to make to ignore all errors.