# make binary error 1: no description

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, makefile, clang

We have a codebase that is compiling just fine on make 3.81 with clang on our Darwin machines.

However, I have uploaded to one of our Linux servers and make 3.81 on that server is giving us:

```
Reaping losing child 0x00dc5be0 PID 14998
make: *** [binary] Error 1
Removing child 0x00dc5be0 PID 14998 from chain.
```

No further information on the error is provided. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535548/make-error-1-error

Comment: There aren't any other error logs from above this? From the commands being run by the `binary` target?

Comment: Find the simplest target that causes the error. Try its commands on the command line. Try writing an even simpler version of that rule. Narrow things down as much as you can, and if you still can't see the problem, come back and give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MichelBillaud I'm really surprised that did not show up in the suggested similar links.

Comment: @EtanReisner there are no other errors at all in the output

Comment: @Beta Thank you that helped solve the initial problem (a library was missing). I did not realize that a process could fail silently and Make would just crash without giving some indication about which process was having an issue.

Comment: It told you the `binary` target was having a problem. If you silence the normal make output that shows you the commands that are being run then it is up to you to display processing status. Are the commands using `@` or are you using `make -s`?

Comment: Interestingly the binary target (gcc) was spitting out all its warnings but I didn't see any errors displayed.