# golangci-lint run command shows errors in makefile

Tags: bash, go, makefile, microservices, golint

I have created a make file to run some bash commands for Go.

[This is check.sh file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4AG8.png)

[This is my make file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuUBK.png)

Error is : `make: *** [Makefile:23: check] Error 1`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8047488/6220193) that happens if one of the commands exits with exit code != 0. That is the case if golangci-lint finds something to complain about.

Try putting the call to golangci-lint directly in the make file.

From my Makefiles:

```
lint:
    golangci-lint run
```

Comment: When i call to golangci-lint directly from Makefile it shows an error that "golangci-lint command not found"

Comment: Is `golangci-lint` in your PATH? Usually it gets installed to $GOPATH/bin which by default is $HOME/go/bin. That folder should be added to the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created mod file in the root folder ?

```
go mod init <root folder /Application Name>
```

if yes, check for the bin folder if the specified package is installed, if not install the package ,

```
go install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@latest
```

Then add it in make file

```
lint:
       golangci-lint run
```